# updating navigation parameters in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate to the same screen from two different place and passing different parameters to show additional contents.

**Navigation code**

```
    // I am navigating to Worklogs screen from both places. 
    // In the first case only passing the current date as parameter
    // and in the second case one extra parameter showPending
    <View style={styles.row}>
          // first touchable. don't want to show pending worklogs if navigated using this
          <Touchable 
            style={styles.widgets}
            onPress={() => this.navigateToScreen('Worklogs', {date: this.getToday()})}
          >
            <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
              <View style={{ flex: 2, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Image 
                  source={require('../assets/images/todayworklog.png')}
                  style={{ resizeMode: 'contain', height: 50}}
                />
              </View>

              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text> Today Worklog </Text>
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 12, color: '#33b0df' }}>{worklogs.total_time} Hours</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Touchable>

          // 2nd touchable. show pending worklogs if navigated from here
          <Touchable 
            style={styles.widgets}
            onPress={() => this.navigateToScreen('Worklogs', {date: this.getToday(), showPending: true})}  
          >
            <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
              <View style={{ flex: 2, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Image 
                  source={require('../assets/images/pendingworklog.png')}
                  style={{ resizeMode: 'contain', height: 50}}
                />
              </View>

              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text> Pending Worklog </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Touchable>
        </View>

  // navigate to screen code
  navigateToScreen(screenName, parameters) {
    if(this.isEmpty(parameters)) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate(screenName);
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate(screenName, parameters);
    }
  }
```

In the render method of Worklogs screen I am checking for the `showPending` value to render an additional component.

```
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

    { (params && params.showPending)
      ? <PendingWorklogList pendingWorklogs={this.state.pending_worklogs} />
      : <View />
    }
```

Now if I navigate to Worklogs screen by tapping the first `<Touchable />`, `showPending` is not in the parameters and `<PendingWorklogList />` component is not being rendered. Navigating from the 2nd `<Touchable />` adds `showPending` to the parameters and `<PendingWorklogList />` is rendered.

But if I go back and navigate to Worklogs again by tapping the first `<Touchable />` the `showPending` parameter is still present so `<PendingWorklogList />` is being rendered. But I would like to render `<PendingWorklogList />` only if I navigate from the 2nd `<Touchable />`.

Comment: maybe send showPending parameter as false rather than not sending at all could work.

Comment: @AlpCoskun, passing false to showPending works. But any idea why the navigation props holding previous value?

Comment: react-navigation don't flush flux store everytime you go back. It will store the screen data in your stackNavigator. When you navigate there again it just override old props. You can use redux if you need more complex data flow.

Comment: Okay. Now i got it. This is my first project in react native so I did not use redux and ran into other problems for that. I would definitely use redux for next projects.